# Como posso encomendar um refrigerante?

Tags: cultura

Um par de anos atrás eu estava em turnê em Portugal. Quando eu pedi um refrigerante de limão, serviram-me duas fatias de limão em uma placa.

O que é o caminho certo para pedir uma bebida refrescante? (como Coca-Cola, mas de limão).

**Edição:** Vistas as respostas (e considerando que tentou encomendar Fanta, Schweppes e Kas, e foram oferecidas estas bebidas com sabor de laranja ou de ananas, mas não limão), eu perguntava a mim mesmo se ele vai estar em Portugal não existe cal de soda (refrigerante com bolhas e com sabor limão).

---

**ENGLISH**

How I can order a soda?

A couple of years ago I was touring in Portugal. When I ordered a lime soda, I was served two slices of lemon on a plate.

What is the right way to order a refreshing drink? (like Coke, but lemon).

**Edit:** Viewing the answers (and considering that I tried to order Fanta, Schweppes and Kas, and were offered these drinks with orange flavor or pineapple, but no lemon), I asked myself if it will be that in Portugal there is no soda lime (soft drink with bubbles and lemon flavor).

Comment: I don't know how it is in Portugal, but here in Brazil the most famous lemon soft drinks are Sprite and Soda Limonada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## In Brazil

To order a refreshing drink:

- "Quero um refrigerante" (not specifying a flavor);
- "Quero um refri" (ditto);
- "Quero uma Coca com limão".

To order a lemon juice/lemonade:

- "Quero um suco de limão" (for lemon juice);
- "Quero uma limonada (for lemonade)".

Comment: Acredito que seja o problema em Portugal especificamente. PS: `Dependendo do lugar, 'refri' pode ser um guarana e não uma soda`

Comment: @MichelAyres É mesmo? Quais? Sou do Sul do Brasil e moro em São Paulo. Em ambos 'refri' não tem sabor.

Comment: Sou do Nordeste e moro no Sul a 10 anos (RS/PR). No Nordeste não há muita utilização de "Refri" mas sim de "Refrigerante" e até mesmo "Refresco", aonde é muitas vezes compreendido como Guarana.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of common ways to ask:

- Ask for something general: Queria um sumo de limão/Queria uma limonada;
- Directly ask for a brand: Queria uma B! de Limão;